# Updating a cell and adding time from data from another cell

Tags: google-apps-script

ok for example I have data(Date/Time) in cell B2 and i want to update cell C2 with the data from B2 but add an hour. Ive tried to just do this locally within google sheets with a formula =B1+1/24 but when i run my script it tells me that the endtime has to be after the start time. it says this because when i enter the formula to the cell it populates a preset date/time (12/30/1899 1:00:00). This casuses my script to fail even though it does add the event to my calendar with a start and end time that is correct, but the rest of the script doesnt run because of the error.

```
function updateCalendar() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
var data = sheet.getRange("A2:E" + last_row).getValues();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CalendarID");


var signups = sheet.getRange("A2:E20").getValues();
for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++)
{   
var shift = signups[x];
var summary = shift[0]
var startTime = shift[1];
var endTime = shift[2];
var volunteer = shift[0];
var description = shift[4];
var location = shift[3];

var event = {
  'location' : location,
  'description' : description,
  'sendInvites' : 'False',
}
cal.createEvent(summary, new Date(startTime), new Date(endTime), event);
}

{   var range = SpreadsheetApp
            .getActive()
            .getSheetByName("Sheet2")
            .getRange("A1:J20");
      range.clearContent();}
      
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? In your situation, it might be required to know your sample Spreadsheet, because I cannot know whether your values are date objects. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.